# I can't dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7!

Tags: dual-boot

I had Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my system (Toshiba Satellite Pro S500), with partitions as below (all on one HDD)

1. Extended partiton
   1.1 Ubuntu 14.04 OS, mounted at / (root dir) FS ext4 200GB (logical partition)
   1.2 Ubuntu User Data, mounted at /home FS ext4 48GB (logical partition)
   1.3 Unallocated Space (to be used for installing Windows 7) 50GB
2. Linux Swap, 2GB (primary partition)

I tried to install Windows 7 on the unallocated space, however it did not work. I tried deleting the unallocated space, however it deleted the OS partition as well as the unallocated space, therefore rendering my Ubuntu not bootable/gone. Windows did not install in the unallocated space at all, leaving me with not a lot. All I have is the windows 7 installer on a USB, GParted ISO on usb and my computer
Any tips?

Comment: Are. You doing a fresh install?

Comment: what about ur /home partition is it gone too.

Comment: If your /home is still available, make a backup of it and start from scratch. Scratch all your partitions, make a new first partition for Windows. Install and when done, create a new Linux ISO on usb or cd. When ready, install Linux in the unpartitioned space (if it's not a multi-user system with dumb users, I would limit the amount of partitions to a strict minimum, rather work with quota if needed for optimum flexibility), and then restore your backup of /home. You can then configure your grub to your prefs to load either Linux or Windows by default.

Answer (score 2):

Windows needs to have write access to the first partition on the disk and that partition has to be a primary one. So if you have non-windows first partition then Windows will fail to install.

Comment: Windows 7 does not need primary partition. Windows XP was the last MS OS that required that.

Comment: @Jakke thanks for pointing that, I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Windows only boots from a primary NTFS formatted partition with the boot flag. You can have the main install in a logical partition, but still have to have one primary to boot from.

Comment: @Jakke it turns that you are wrong. Credible Microsoft source http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-are-partitions-and-logical-drives says that - I am quoting linked resource - "Logical drives function like primary partitions except that they cannot be used to start an operating system".

Answer (score 0):

First make the raw partition in the windows HDD and then try to perform install ubuntu on that raw partition.
It causes error because linux and windows both uses different file system ie; windows uses NTFS and Linux uses EXT that's why it is not being installed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment since I am not at rep level 50, otherwise I would :)
My /home is still there (thank goodness, I have homework on that partition!)
Raphael I am doing a fresh install of Windows 7
Jakke (regarding backups) I was (will) do that, I have a DVD with a Ubuntu 12.04 64bit ISO file and a USB with nothing on, so I could use Unetbootin/UniversalUSBCreator to make the ISO bootable on the USB on my OLD laptop. A Compaq Armada M700. With USB 1.
How long would that take to get bootable? Or should I just wait for 2 days for the next school day and get it done quicker there with USB 2?
Jakke I am going to what you advised, although my friend has a Samsung N150 (plus?), and he tried to install Windows 7 after having Linux Mint 17 on there. Windows would not let him install, like me, even though there is only one partition on the drive (NTFS), with the same generic error. I am worried the same will happen to me :(

I am only installing Windows 7 so I can print easier
So much hassle for printing